# Set new heading for included multi-page document

Tags: sectioning

In a large base document

```
\documentclass[10pt,onecolumn]{article}
```

I use

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markboth{ }{my main document heading text}
```

to set the headings.

I am also using the pdfpages package to include a multi-page document within my base document as follows:

```
\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=.95]{myMultiPageDocument.pdf}
```

I would like to set the heading within the base document showing the added document and tried

```
\markboth{ }{my new heading text here}

\includepdf[pages={1-},scale=.95]{myMultiPageDocument.pdf}
```

but no headings were rendered.  (I cannot set headings within myMultiPageDocument.pdf.)

How do I create new headings for the pages showing the included document?

Comment: Add `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{myheadings}}` or `\pagecommand={}` to the options of `\includepdf`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could be solved in comments

Comment: I think a question should not be closed off just because it can be solved in comments.  Sometimes short obscure answers are the hardest to find.  And this problem is certainly not "off-topic" generally, since it relates directly to LaTeX typesetting.